# ¿Como crear un contador alfanumerico en vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Buenas tengo una duda en cuanto a al realización de un contador alfanumérico incrementable en `visual basic.net` alguna idea de como podría hacerse?

El formato del contador seria de la siguiente forma:

`PRE-001/13/12/2016`

Este es un simple contador numérico pero no puedo adaptarlo con otro tipo de datos como string, mejor dicho no tengo una idea de como hacerlo
en el evento load del `form1` cada vez que se habra el programa automáticamente aumente en el numero de uno en uno y capture la fecha actual:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Dim con As Integer
Dim sufijo As String
Dim fecha As Date
sufijo= "PRE"
fecha =  DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") 
        con = 0
        con = con + 1
        txtnumero.Text = sufijo+con+fecha

 End Sub
```

Incluyendo la palabra `PRE`  al inicio, el numero del presupuesto generado (que es el que se va a incrementar de uno en uno) seguido de la fecha de creación es posible esto en `vb.net`?

Comment: Hola, primero de todo, que código has intentado tú? No estamos para hacer el trabajo por tí, sino para ayudarte a solucionar un problema basándonos en lo que tú has intentado. Segundo, ¿qué es lo que quieres incrementar? ¿la fecha?, ¿el número de presupuesto?. A mi entender no está muy clara la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Con este codigo se puede generar una cadena asi:

> PRE-001/14/12/2016

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim con As Integer
    Dim sufijo As String
    Dim fecha As Date
    sufijo = "PRE-"
    fecha = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    con = 0
    con = con + 1
    Dim out As String = con.ToString("000")
    txtNumero.Text = sufijo & out & "/" & fecha
  End Sub
```

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios los revisare cuando pueda y les aviso!

Answer (score 1):

Bueno tu idea no parece muy complicada pero está algo confusa. Primero el contador lo deberías guardar en algún lugar (Por ejemplo: base de datos, archivos de texto, libros de Excell, etc.) o si no es necesario que lo guardes bueno lo debes almacenar en una variable con mayor ambito. Es decir, por lo que escribes, parece que piensas cerrar el formulario y al abrirlo generar el nuevo contador, si esto es así, podrías crear un Modulo y ahi una variable que se llame contador y luego la vas incrementando accediendo a ella cada vez que tu lo veas conveniente.

Tal vez podrías explicar un poco más el tema y así poder ayudarte con mayor precisión.

Answer (score 1):

En base a tu necesidad, yo sugiero que guardes en app.config el prefijo y el consecutivo, te anexo el código de ejemplo para que te des una idea:

Necesita agregar la referencia de: `System.Configuration`

```
Imports System.Configuration
```

El código en el form sería:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Dim prefijo, consecutivo As String
        prefijo = LeerAppConfig("prefijo")
        consecutivo = LeerAppConfig("consecutivo")

        Dim cons As Integer = Integer.Parse(IIf(consecutivo = "", "0", consecutivo))
        cons = cons + 1

        txtFolio.Text = prefijo + "-" + cons.ToString("000") + "/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

        ''Guardo en app.config
        GuardarAppConfig("consecutivo",cons)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub

private function LeerAppConfig(key As String) as string
        Dim result As String = ""
    Try
        Dim appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
        result= appSettings(key)
        If IsNothing(result) Then
            result = "Not found"
        End If
    Catch e As ConfigurationErrorsException
        Console.WriteLine("Error reading app settings")
    End Try
        return result
End function

private sub GuardarAppConfig(key As String, value As String) 
    Try
        Dim configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
        Dim settings = configFile.AppSettings.Settings
        If IsNothing(settings(key)) Then
            settings.Add(key, value)
        Else
            settings(key).Value = value
        End If
        configFile.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(configFile.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name)
    Catch e As ConfigurationErrorsException
        Console.WriteLine("Error writing app settings")
    End Try
End sub
```

y tu archivo `app.config` quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="prefijo" value="PRE" />
    <add key="consecutivo" value="0" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Anexo imágenes:

[image: Imagen de la referencia]

[image: Ejemplo del Form1]

[image: Aplicación corriendo]

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios los revisare cuando pueda y les aviso!